# Understanding "Markov Chains" by Norris Theorems 1.7.5 and 6

Tags: probability, markov-chains

On this page: [https://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/~james/Markov/s17.pdf](https://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/%7Ejames/Markov/s17.pdf)
I am trying to understand what $\gamma^k$ represents and how it is used concretely with Theorems 1.7.5 and 1.7.6. Does Theorem 1.7.6 mean that if the chain is recurrent, $\gamma^k$ is just a vector of $1$'s? I am trying to use this to work out question 1.7.3 on the same page.

For a fixed state k, $\gamma_i^k=E_k \sum_{n=0}^{T_k-1}1_{\{X_n=i\}}$

Theorem 1.7.5:
Let P be irreducible and recurrent.
Then,

1. $\gamma^k_k=1$
2. $\gamma^k=\{\gamma_i^k : i \in I\}$ satisfies $\gamma^k P = \gamma^k$.
3. $0 < \gamma_i^k < \infty$ for all $i$

Theorem 1.7.6:
Let $P$ be irreducible and let $\lambda$ be an invariant measure for $P$ with $\lambda_k=1$. Then $\lambda \geq \gamma^k$. If $P$ is also recurrent, then $\lambda=\gamma^k$.

Exercise 1.7.3 discusses a particle moving along the edges of a cube. I need to find the number of visits through vertex $o$ until the first return to vertex $i$ ($o$ is the opposite vertex of $i$) and the expected number of steps until the first visit to $o$.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It would be very nice of you if you edit and include the actual Theorems  or questions in your post rather than just citing them so it would be easier for your readers.

Comment: Sorry about that! Just fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

For a state $k$ in the state space $I$, let the random variable $T_k \mathrel{\vcenter{:}}= \inf\{\,n \geq 1 : X_n =  k\,\}$ denote the first passage time of state $k$. Intuitively, if the Markov chain $(X_n)$ starts at state $k$, then $T_k$ represents the first time the Markov chain returns to state $k$, excluding the starting state. Then for states $k$ and $i$, the object $\gamma_i^k \mathrel{\vcenter{:}}= \mathbb{E}_k \left(\sum_{n=0}^{T_k - 1}\mathbf{1}_{\{X_n = i\}}\right)$ is the numerical answer to the following question:
$$
\text{"If we start at state } k \text{, how many visits do we expect to make to state } i \text{ before we return to state }k \text{?"}
$$
where we include the starting state at $k$ (since $n=0$ is included in the sum) and exclude the return to $k$ (since we do not include $n = T_k$ in the sum). We define the vector $\gamma^k \mathrel{\vcenter{:}}= \left(\,\gamma_i^k :  i\in I\,\right)$ of the number of expected visits to each state $i$ between consecutive visits to state $k$.

Now let us discuss the two theorems you asked about. I will only give handwavy explanations for the theorems, since you can read the proper proofs in Norris's book.

**Theorem 1.7.5**. Let $P$ be irreducible and recurrent, and let $k$ be a state. Then

1. $\gamma_k^k = 1$,
2. $\gamma^k P = \gamma^k$, and
3. for all states i, we have $0 < \gamma_i^k < \infty$.

*Explanation*. The first part of the theorem says we expect to visit the state $k$ once between consecutive visits to state $k$. This should be obvious: we started at state $k$, so of course we will visit state $k$ at least once. Then we exclude the return to state $k$ in the calculation of $\gamma_k^k$, so we only visit state $k$ at most once. The third part of the theorem says we expect to visit state $i$ more than zero times, but we expect the number of visits to only be finite. This follows from the assumption of $P$ being irreducible. If $\gamma_i^k = 0$ then we expect to never visit state $i$ before returning to state k. If $\gamma_i^k = \infty$ then we expect to never return to state $k$ after visiting state $i$. Both cases go against the irreducibility and recurrence of $P$. The second part of the theorem is the most interesting part: it says the vector $\gamma^k$ is an invariant measure for $P$. Writing $P = (p_{i,j})_{i,j\in I}$, for each state $j$ we have
$$
\left(\gamma^k P\right)_j = \sum_{i \in I} \gamma^k_ip_{i,j}
$$
which, roughly speaking, averages over the number of times we visit state $i$ followed immediately by visiting state $j$, all between consecutive visits to state $k$. Brushing the details of the brute calculation under the carpet, this gives the average number of times state $j$ is visited between consecutive visits to state $k$, which is precisely $\gamma_j^k$. You can see parallels between this line of thinking and the proof presented in Norris's book.

**Theorem 1.7.6**. Let $P$  be irreducible and let $\lambda$ be an invariant measure for $P$, with $\lambda_k = 1$ for some state $k$. Then $\lambda \geq \gamma^k$. Furthermore, if $P$ is recurrent then $\lambda = \gamma^k$.

*Explanation*. The first part says if $\lambda$ is an invariant measure with a non-zero entry in the $k$-th position, then rescaling $\lambda$ so that $\lambda_k = 1$ will ensure that all the entries of $\lambda$ will be at least as large as $\gamma^k$, i.e. $\lambda_j \geq \gamma^k_j$ for all states $j$. The main part of the theorem is the second part, which says that if $P$ is recurrent then we actually have $\lambda = \gamma^k$. So if $\lambda$ is an invariant measure with non-zero entry in the $k$-th position, then $\lambda$ actually *equals* $\gamma^k$ up to scaling. This, in effect, gives some uniqueness to invariant measures of $P$. To answer your question, this does *not* say that $\gamma^k$ is a vector of 1's; it just implies that the $k$-th position of $\gamma^k$ equals 1, as we expect due to the first part of **Theorem 1.7.5**.

Now, for the **Exercise 1.7.3** you mentioned, you would like to find the value of $\gamma_o^i$. You can check that the transition matrix associated with this Markov chain is irreducible and recurrent, so $\gamma^i$ would equal any invariant measure whose $i$-th entry is equal to $1$ by **Theorem 1.7.6**. You would therefore solve the left-eigenvector equation $\lambda P = \lambda$, where $P$ is the transition matrix for the particle, and among those which have $\lambda_i \neq 0$ you would rescale it so it's $i$-th position is equal to 1. This rescaled eigenvector would equal $\gamma^i$, so you may then read off the value of $\gamma_o^i$.